# I cannot import modules inside of my package located in site-packages; what should I do?

Tags: python, package, site-packages

I have made a package located here: `/home/saunderstock1/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`.

When I try to import any modules in any of the python files located in said package, I get an `ImportError`.

I assume this has to do with the package's location. What should I do?

Comment: What other packages are installed there? Can you successfully import any of those?

Comment: @quamrana I have pygame, along with custom files installed there. I tried importing pygame, and was given an `ImportError`. I assume that it just looks inside of the package instead of where it usually looks because the package is in site-packages.

Comment: Maybe the version of python you are running doesn't look in that location

Comment: @quamrana Yeah, for some reason when I run a file in a package with vscode, it uses `python -u`. Thanks!